# cell(...).data(...).draw is not a function

Tags: datatables

I am updating values of two cells using the following code

```
/*-----------------Agent Presence Websocket Starts-----------------------------*/
function presenceConnect(existing_table){
  var agentPresenceSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(wsStart+domain+"/agent-presence/");

  agentPresenceSocket.onmessage = function(e){

    data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    console.log(data);

    var availability = data['availability'];
    var id = data['id'];
    var upn  = data['upn'];
    var timeInStatus = data['timeInStatus'];

    var rowId = $('#agent-table').dataTable()
    .fnFindCellRowIndexes(upn, 0);

    if(rowId.length>0){
      if(yellowArray.includes(availability)){
        existing_table
        .cell(rowId, 6)
        .data('<i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg yellow-light"></i>'+availability)
        .draw(false);
      };
      if(greenArray.includes(availability)){
       existing_table
       .cell(rowId, 6)
       .data('<i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg green-light"></i>'+availability)
       .draw(false);
     };
     if(redArray.includes(availability)){
       existing_table
       .cell(rowId, 6)
       .data('<i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg red-light"></i>'+availability)
       .draw(false);
     }
     if(availability=="DoNotDisturb"){
       existing_table
       .cell(rowId, 6)
       .data('<i class="fa fa-ban fa-lg red-light"></i>'+availability)
       .draw(false);
     }

     existing_table
       .cell(rowId, 7)
       .data(timeInStatus)
       .draw(false);
     console.log("Time in status updated");

   };
  };
}
/*-----------------Agent Presence Websocket Ends-----------------------------*/
```

For the 6th cell values are getting changed but for the 7th cell i am getting this error though code is same for both the cells

```
Uncaught TypeError: existing_table.cell(...).data(...).draw is not a function
```

P.S: `exisiting_table` is an instance of DataTable()

Sample data

```
{ upn: "abc@example.com", id: 613, activity: "Busy", availability: "Busy", time: "3:40:33" }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show a sample of the source (JSON?) data.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Should `var timeInStatus = data['timeInStatus'];` actually be `var timeInStatus = data['time'];`?

Comment: @andrewjames To gather sample data for you i logged into console, Then i see where the issue was. I was using the wrong ```key``` name i.e ```data['timeInStatus']``` , rather it must be ```data['time']```. Thanks for giving your time to this question. You have helped me earlier as well.

Comment: @andrewjames Can you please answer this question.I will accept it or suggest what should i do. Now everything is working fine. Thanks again

Comment: It was just a minor oversight. If you want to, I think you can provide an answer yourself (SO encourages that). Maybe if you provide details on how you solved it (how you used the console) then that may be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged data into the browser's console. What i got is below:

```
{ upn: "abc@example.com", id: 613, activity: "Busy", availability: "Busy", time: "3:40:33" }
```

To gather time i was using the wrong key name i.e `timeInStatus`
.Thus the value of  `data['timeInStatus']` is `undefined`. That's why `existing_table.cell().data().draw()` was throwing error.

When i used the correct key name i.e `time` i didn't get any error.